# ERROR 1247 (42S22): Reference 'VITORIAS' not supported (reference to group function)

Tags: mysql

I am not able to create a view. Below you can find my code. Can somebody help me?

```
CREATE VIEW V_Campeonato AS SELECT team.tim_cod_inscri_time
        , SUM( CASE WHEN partida.par_gol_mand > partida.par_gol_visi  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS VITORIAS
        , SUM( CASE WHEN partida.par_gol_mand = partida.par_gol_visi  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS EMPATES
        , SUM( CASE WHEN partida.par_gol_mand < partida.par_gol_visi  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS DERROTAS
FROM team 
INNER JOIN partida 
ON team.tim_cod_inscri_time = partida.par_cod_partida
ORDER BY ( VITORIAS * 3 + EMPATES ) DESC;
```

> ERROR 1247 (42S22): Reference 'VITORIAS' not supported (reference to
>   group function)

Comment: You can't `SUM` and `CASE` at the same time.  I think from your code you want to output a 1 or a 0, not a SUM of 1's or 0's.

Comment: Can you rephrase this code for me?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to fully understand what you are going for in this code.  But, this may be what you are after:

```
 SELECT SUM(VITORIAS), SUM(EMPATES), SUM(DERROTAS), tim_cod_inscri_time FROM

    (SELECT
    (CASE WHEN partida.par_gol_mand > partida.par_gol_visi THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS VITORIAS , 
    (CASE WHEN partida.par_gol_mand = partida.par_gol_visi THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS EMPATES , 
    (CASE WHEN partida.par_gol_mand < partida.par_gol_visi THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS DERROTAS
    FROM team INNER JOIN partida ON team.tim_cod_inscri_time = partida.par_cod_partida)
    AS teamrecord
    GROUP BY tim_cod_inscri_time
    ORDER BY ( VITORIAS * 3 + EMPATES ) DESC;
```

I pulled the `SUM` out of the inner table, and summarized the wins separately.  Also, I gave the subquery an arbitrary name, `teamrecord`.  Is this what you were going for?

Comment: Hello, I'm pulling from the CODE team, the victories, defeats and draws the team in several matches!

Comment: What you did is right, what is wanted from cod_inscri_time, pull all draws, defeats and victories that TIME. A view to the team! If you can help me, Thanks Sable Fost.

Comment: Updated with a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: If this solved the problem, please select the solution as correct, to close it out, and help others who may search with a similar problem!